# Is it possible to override bunyan's log functions?

Tags: node.js, bunyan

I'm using bunyan.js as my logging solution and I would like to add functionality to it's logging functions.

For example I would like to send something to a third party API each time there's a call to log.fatal()

Is that possible? I looked through the docs and I didn't see any events I can register to, or any other solution.

Thanks!

Comment: There are quite a lot of Bunyan stream plugins for logging to external services, perhaps you can check out how those are implemented ([start here](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=bunyan)).

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't find any that would help me (my goal is sending alerts to datadog)

Comment: But you can check their source, how they implement adding logging functionality to Bunyan. It should be fairly easy, as Bunyan works with streams, so you could implement a stream class that would push log messages to Datadog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bunyan has it's "streams": https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#streams
Every logger can write to multiple streams.

You can either specify additional streams while creating logger object, or use `addStream` method (it is not mentioned in their readme, but it's a public method, that logger uses internally too), for example:

```
logger.addStream({
    type: 'raw',
    stream: new MyDatadog(),
    closeOnExit: true,
    // Here you specify what level should be written to this stream.
    // For example, you can use soemthing like `logger.FATAL` here.
    level: options.level
});
```

And then:

```
function MyDatadog () {
    // initialize whatever is needed here
}

MyDatadog.prototype.write = function write (record) {
    // write record data wherever you want
    // record is an object with things like:
    // - record.what
    // - record.time
    // - record.err
};

MyDatadog.prototype.end = function end () {
    // cleanup stuff here
};
```

Of course, creating own wrapper is not needed if whatever you use (some datadog library?) gives you writable stream which accepts writing JS objects.

Comment: Thats great! 
I can implement MyDatadog as ES6 class no?
Also, what does closeOnExit determine?

Comment: Check their source for more info: https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan/blob/cbfaa9a7bd86c658dbb8333c894191d23b65be33/lib/bunyan.js#L331 and https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan/blob/cbfaa9a7bd86c658dbb8333c894191d23b65be33/lib/bunyan.js#L544 - if true, bunyan should automatically close your stream, but i'm not sure it actually does that.